# Removing code from GitHub

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to entirely remove a directory and its history from GitHub?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you are asking about deleting a project from GitHub, open your project, click the "Admin" tab (or browse directly to https://github.com/username/project_name/edit) and on the bottom of the page, click "Delete This Repository". It'll ask you to confirm this, and then it's gone.

If you just want to erase a part of your repository, you need to do it to your git repository and push it to GitHub.

GitHub has written [a howto about this](http://github.com/guides/completely-remove-a-file-from-all-revisions) in their FAQ. I Haven't tried this myself, so I can't guide you further, but you probably can manage this yourself here on.

In either case, this, naturally, doesn't delete any third party pulls – if someone has pulled the repository before you deleted it, it's out, without you being able to do much about it (other than trying the "pretty please"-technique).

Comment: I don't know where I heard that first, but there is a nice saying in the Git community: "Git works just like the real world: if you want to rewrite history, you need a conspiracy". IOW, if you want to remove a directory from the history, everybody who ever cloned that repository has to be "in on it"

Comment: Yeah, that, or they mistakenly pull from the central git repo. I guess that way their local histories would be erased too, although I'm not sure...

Comment: No, they won't. Old history only gets deleted when it is no longer referenced by anything *and* you run the garbage collector. Which means that by default it won't get deleted for at least 2 weeks, because that's how long they will stay in the reflog. As long as they are in the reflog, you just ...

Comment: ... do `git checkout HEAD@{10.minutes.ago}` and you're back in business.

In distributed version control, you have *no control* over what anybody else does with their repositories. That's the *point* of DVCS. (No *technical* control. You could have *social* controls, like work contracts.)

Answer (score 14):

To selectively delete a file or directory (and all its associated history), you can use `git filter-branch`.

This is very useful when you want to completely delete files checked into the repository by mistake.

The syntax is simple:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f filename' HEAD
```

More info on the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question asked by the author, however it is definitely useful.

Answer (score 4):

This is the easiest way the deletes a directory from your GitHub repo but not local system:

```
git rm -r --cached FolderName
git commit -m "Removed folder from repository"
git push origin master
```

Comment: it works but this doesn't remove commit history though

Answer (score 3):

Go to the edit tab; there’s a delete link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Not as in-depth as the expected answer. Did not mention name of label, what side of the page, etc.