# What's happened to my directory on GitHub?

Tags: git, directory, github, git-submodules

I added a new subdir within my git respository:

```
git add feeds
```

Then commited this and pushed it up to GitHub but it seems as though I've commited a symlink / shortcut but not the actual directory and files within.

See here: http://github.com/G4EGK/RSS-Reader

Any idea what 'feeds' is?

I'd like to remove that and correctly add my files. I tried the following but `git status` said nothing had changed:

```
git rm feeds
git add feeds/\*.php
```

To remove feeds do I run [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443896/removing-code-from-github/1075452#1075452)?

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f feeds' HEAD
```

---

### Update

Thanks Wes.

```
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--@  1 greg  staff  890  2 Apr 19:11 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  10 greg  staff  340  3 Apr 09:30 feeds
-rw-r--r--@  1 greg  staff  372  2 Apr 19:24 rssreader.php
drwxr-xr-x   3 greg  staff  102  2 Apr 15:23 tests
drwxr-xr-x   7 greg  staff  238  2 Apr 15:44 transfer
$ git submodule feeds
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'feeds'
```

`git filter-branch` didn't remove this submodule from my repo (it was still tracked when I viewed `git status`)

To remove this mistake I [reverted the last two commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github/448929#448929) (where I tried to add feed classes).

```
$ git log
commit 276b2392....
Author: Greg K <...@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Apr 3 23:40:14 2010 +0100

    Add feed classes

commit d9814942....
Author: Greg K <...@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Apr 3 23:37:52 2010 +0100

    Add feed classes

commit 2b7fb93a....
Author: Greg K <...@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 2 19:47:09 2010 +0100

    Use auto-detect line length for fgets()
```

Used the command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Then I deleted commits 2 & 3, leaving the top line (my commit on April 2nd), saved my changes (:wq) and forced a push to GitHub.

```
git push origin +master
```

Now my GitHub repo is back to where I was before adding feeds.

My original mistake was forgetting to use a slash at the end when adding feeds initially. I should have used

```
git add feeds/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you added `feeds` as a submodule.  Check out the commit:
http://github.com/G4EGK/RSS-Reader/commit/276b2392acd2abbd1fadb310768796675d287771

Check `git submodule status`