# Git is ignoring subdirectory upload

Tags: git, assembla

I am new to Git and I'm trying to get a subfolder uploaded into my 'master'project but currently unable to. I have gotten all the files in the root folder uploaded through Git and can push and clone the root folder. I have a folder called 'includes' in the root folder (root/includes) with 5 .php files in it I would like to upload. Currently, there is a folder called "includes" when I clone the project, but there are no files in it. The files that were placed in the "includes" folder was copied from another project. I have tried cloning the project again and pushing the files in the "includes" folder, but with no luck.The following is my command trail after I clone the project and successfully retrieve the root files:

```
add -A includes
cd includes
add -A 
cd ../
commit -a -m "uploading includes folder"
git push origin
```

Assembla shows that there are no files in the folder.In fact, the folder is shown as a file.  Is it possible that the includes folder is being seen as a submodule? If I commit inside the folder, the files are then listed with "create mode" in front of them.

---

When I push the folder, there are files in the includes folder. Here is an output I am getting after adding a "config.php" file in the includes folder:

```
add config.php
fatal: Path 'includes/config.php' is in submodule 'includes'
```

I didn't make the subdirectory a submodule, but it is appearing as one?

Comment: Can you show the output of `git status` after adding the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no files in the directory git will not stage the directory when you run `git add`. Git does not care about files and directories like SVN, it tracks content changes.

See [does git ignore empty folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders)

**Update**

Since you have updated your question, I'll update my response. What you've done is an easy mistake to make, if you run `git add directory` with no end `/` this can add a submodule to your repository.

See my own question last year: [What's happened to my directory on Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573086/whats-happened-to-my-directory-on-github)

Answer (score 2):

Ah, your update indicates that you've got *submodules* in the mix. If you don't know what those are, then it was probably an accident (and is easy to fix). You will probably find that you have both a `.git` directory in your main directory, *and* an `includes/.git` directory.

The solution to your problem is to remove the `includes/.git` directory:

```
rm -rf includes/.git
```

Normally, Git stores all its metadata in the single `.git` subdirectory at the top of your directory tree. However, if you're using submodules, then other directories will also contain `.git` directories.