# Removing directory from the entire history in git

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm working with a legacy project that included in the repository a directory that should have been ignored. The contents of this directory is causing a huge number of irrelevant conflicts while rebasing.

Is there a way to completely remove this directory from the history (as if it had been gitignored from the beginning)?

Comment: Only if you've never pushed the changes, and no one's ever pulled them from you.  Even in that case, though, you'd have to muck around with every commit that touched the affected files.

Comment: You want `git filter-branch`.  Beware that this will break pulls.  (Like rebase)

Comment: Duplicate of [Removing code from GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/q/443896/578288) (in terms of the answers, not necessarily the question). See [GitHub Help: Remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data), which the top answer links to.

Comment: @SLaks Please add this as an answer, and I'll accept it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `git filter-branch`, which will rewrite every commit in your branch.

Beware that this will break pulls (just like rebase).